# Should I let users create tables within the database or create views?

Tags: php, database-design

I'm using cakephp and I need to let users design their own forms (this will only be done once during a setup wizard stage, with about 12 forms created in real use).  Tables that always will be needed, are users, groups, and logs, settings. Effectively this is a user friendly database app.

I was thinking create Views and having two actual tables to store the form and subsequent data that comes in:

```
Forms [id | name   | structure                                                   ]
      [1  | Details| {id:{type:key}q2:{type:text;validation:{select:male..}..}   ]
      [2  | Car    | {id:{type:key};car:{type:text;validation:{select:Honda... }}]
```

The column "structure" would contain a json or xml string listing the fields, type and validation rules.

```
Forms_data [id | form_id | survey_id | key  | value ]
           [1  | 1       | 1         | q1   |  Male ]
           [2  | 1       | 1         | q2   | 1/1/76]
           [3  | 2       | 1         | Car  |  Honda]
           [4  | 2       | 1         | Eng  | Petrol]
           [5  | 1       | 2         | q1   |  Fem  ]
           [6  | 1       | 2         | q2   | 2/3/81]
           [7  | 2       | 2         | Car  |  Ford ]
           [8  | 2       | 2         | Eng  | Diesel]
```

The Forms_data table would contain data for each field of the form, survey_id means the subject person the forms are about, one person being surveyed can have many forms done about them.  Key will be varchar but value will have to be the size of the largest possible data type (eg "Paragraph text").

Or should I let users (via params/sanitised etc.) execute a "CREATE TABLE" and create real tables in the database, so I get the full advantage of the systems querying and optimisation and in cakephp get all the magic function working?

Comment: You should do neither table creation nor view creation, both are awful ideas and even if you sanitize input and what not, I can create N accounts and pollute your database, effectively making it a nightmare to maintain due to tables/views. Edit: I saw that you actually won't create a view each time a form is created, therefore - yes, create a view and the two underlying tables you need, it's by far safer option than creating tables.

Comment: What if there is an elevated Super User account (limited by IP address) that can run the create table code part of the app?

Comment: If you create forms on the fly, you don't create tables that hold the data. Yes, it would be great if we could do that, you'd query exactly one table (or set of tables), but relational databases aren't meant for that. You either go with EAV approach here, where your tables are already created and their schema supports infinitely -growing form with all the fields and values or simply use schema-less data storage layer, like MongoDB or similar NoSQL solutions which don't rely on a structure. The moment you think that you need to create tables on the fly - you've done something wrong.

Comment: As there won't be an unlimited amount of forms created, just a set number during a the "setup" stage, during which they will have a temp user account for setting up the database.  EAV approach is complex and I will lose the cakephp magic.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to do with the data later and how much there will be. DBMS systems (such as MySQL) deal with large amounts of data very fast. You can also query the data in very sophisticated ways as opposed to your other choices. The trade-off is a little more complexity. I almost always come down on the side of a database solution. It gives you the most flexibility.